# Installing windows 8, cannot find a location to store temporary

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

Im trying to install windows 8 from a iso file, because i lack an optical drive.
Though I'm getting an error when running the mounted install.
I'm Running windows 7. Because I could not get my iso file to be bootable for windows 8

> Windows Setup cannot find a location to store temporary installation
>   files. To install windows, make sure that a partition on your boot
>   disk has at least 1010 megabytes(MB) of free space
>   Error code 0x80070490

This I do have, My disc is almost empty a new 256gb samsung ssd.

I have tried this solution:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_update/window-update-error-windowsupdate80070005/a9a2c92d-793b-4050-bdb1-720bb97bd78d
(subinacl + reset)

Help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldnt install temporary files on the ssd, as soon as I plugged in my internal wd green, then it went right through